# Subset df using timestamps - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to subset a df using specific timestamps plus an additional period of time. Using below, `df` contains specific timestamps that I want to use to subset `df2`. Essentially, I use the timestamps in df and determine the previous minute. These periods of time are then used to create individual df's, which are concatenated together to create the final df.

However, this is inefficient by itself, but becomes even more so when dealing with multiple times.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : ['2020-08-02 10:01:12.5','2020-08-02 11:01:12.5','2020-08-02 12:31:00.0','2020-08-02 12:41:22.6'],             
        'ID' : ['X','Y','B','X'],                 
    })

# 1 min before timestamp
'2020-08-02 10:00:12.5' 
# first timestamp
'2020-08-02 10:01:12.5' 

# 1 min before timestamp
'2020-08-02 11:00:02.1' 
# second timestamp
'2020-08-02 11:01:02.1' 

 df2 = pd.DataFrame({   
        'Time' : ['2020-08-02 10:00:00.1','2020-08-02 10:00:00.2','2020-08-02 10:00:00.3','2020-08-02 10:00:00.4'],             
        'ID' : ['','','',''],                 
    })

d1 = df2[(df2['Time'] > '2020-08-02 10:00:12.5') & (df2['Time'] <= '2020-08-02 10:01:12.5')]
d2 = df2[(df2['Time'] > '2020-08-02 11:00:02.1') & (df2['Time'] <= '2020-08-02 11:01:02.1')]

df_out = pd.concat([d1,d2])#...include all separate periods of time
```

Intended Output:

```
                    Time ID
   2020-08-02 10:00:12.5  
   2020-08-02 10:00:12.6  
...
   2020-08-02 11:01:12.5  X
   2020-08-02 11:00:02.1
   2020-08-02 11:00:02.2
...
   2020-08-02 11:01:02.1  Y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) method in pandas that does just that.

Let me use slightly different timestamps compared to the original post to make it a bit easier to illustrate. I'll set `df1` timestamps at `10:01`, `10:03` and `10:06` for the purpose of this example.

Let's add `1MinBefore` column to `df` with the timestamp one minute before the `Time` (we'll use it later to merge the dataframes):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : ['2020-08-02 10:01:00','2020-08-02 10:03:00','2020-08-02 10:06:00'],
    'ID' : ['X','Y','Z'],                 
})
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['1MinBefore'] = df['Time'] - pd.Timedelta('1min')
```

So our `df` is:

```
                 Time ID          1MinBefore
0 2020-08-02 10:01:00  X 2020-08-02 10:00:00
1 2020-08-02 10:03:00  Y 2020-08-02 10:02:00
2 2020-08-02 10:06:00  Z 2020-08-02 10:05:00
```

Let's use the range between `10:00` and `10:07` with 30 second intervals for `df2`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({   
    'Time' : pd.date_range(
        start='2020-08-02 10:00:00',
        end='2020-08-02 10:07:00',
        freq='30s'),
    'ID' : '',
})
```

And now the key step, merging these dataframes with `merge_asof`:

```
pd.merge_asof(df2[['Time']], df[['ID', '1MinBefore']],
              left_on='Time', right_on='1MinBefore',
              tolerance=pd.Timedelta('1min')
```

Output:

```
                  Time   ID          1MinBefore
0  2020-08-02 10:00:00    X 2020-08-02 10:00:00
1  2020-08-02 10:00:30    X 2020-08-02 10:00:00
2  2020-08-02 10:01:00    X 2020-08-02 10:00:00
3  2020-08-02 10:01:30  NaN                 NaT
4  2020-08-02 10:02:00    Y 2020-08-02 10:02:00
5  2020-08-02 10:02:30    Y 2020-08-02 10:02:00
6  2020-08-02 10:03:00    Y 2020-08-02 10:02:00
7  2020-08-02 10:03:30  NaN                 NaT
8  2020-08-02 10:04:00  NaN                 NaT
9  2020-08-02 10:04:30  NaN                 NaT
10 2020-08-02 10:05:00    Z 2020-08-02 10:05:00
11 2020-08-02 10:05:30    Z 2020-08-02 10:05:00
12 2020-08-02 10:06:00    Z 2020-08-02 10:05:00
13 2020-08-02 10:06:30  NaN                 NaT
14 2020-08-02 10:07:00  NaN                 NaT
```

The `tolerance` parameter of 1 minute basically tells it that values in `df` 'older' than 1 minute should be disregarded.

Now we can of course drop `1MinBefore` column and use `fillna` on the `ID` column to make it look exactly like the `Intended Output` in the original post.